# Installing tm package in R

Tags: r, linux

I am facing problem while installing tm package in r version 3.2.3. I have tried implementing different ways available in internet and the stack overflow answers. I don't know where I am going wrong.

It shows

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     namespace ‘slam’ 0.1-32 is being loaded, but >= 0.1.37 is required
>
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tm’
>   * removing ‘/home/alankrita/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/tm’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPSKOOW/downloaded_packages’"

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: use `install.packages("slam")` to update the slam package.

Comment: Or `update.packages()` to update all of your installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading my version of R to the latest version, and then trying the install tm package again. If you're on Linux you can do this quite easily by adding the Cran site to your repository list, and then updating your version of r-base.

For Ubuntu users a good description of adding the Cran repo can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2). Once you've pointed your system to the Cran repo  the upgrade of the r version can be achieved with:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```